# error.phtml is being displayed (Page not found error)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am a beginner working with Zend Framework, and currently having a small problem:

I am creating a project based on modular architecture and requesting this URL:

http://localhost/MyApp/public/ --> which is where index.php resides. My core module is called "core" inside /application/modules directory as follows:

```
/Applications/modules/
-- Core
---- controllers
------ ErrorController.php
------ IndexController.php
---- views
------ scripts
-------- error/error.phtml
-------- index/index.phtml.
```

Everytime i refresh the page i get error.phtml displayed which is weird. Because my module does define it's routes as follows:

```
[routes]
routes.core_index_index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.core_index_index.route = "/"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.module = "core"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.action = "index"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.frontend = "true"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.langKey = "route_index_page_description"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.localization.enable = "true"
```

Plus the fact that i do have RewriteBase set to /var/www/html/MyApp/public. So why is my error.phtml being displayed while index.phtml should be the view script to be rendered?

Following is my setup for production config in application.ini

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = core
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

Content of error page being displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Zend Framework Default Application</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>An error occurred</h1>
  <h2>Page not found</h2>


</body>
</html>
```

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Is there an Exception thrown? What is the Content of the error?

Comment: See modification in my post please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got this to work:

Since am requesting http://localhost/MyApp/public/, i had to modify the routing to:

```
[routes]
routes.core_index_index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.core_index_index.route = "/MyApp/public/"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.module = "core"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.action = "index"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.frontend = "true"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.langKey = "route_index_page_description"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.localization.enable = "true"
```

Change was from:

```
routes.core_index_index.route = "/"
```

To:

```
routes.core_index_index.route = "/MyApp/public/"
```

Which is not exactly what i was looking for. Is there a way to skip /MyApp/public part of the URI?

Answer (score 0):

index.php is the frontController.
ModRewrite should send requests to MyApp/ to MyApp/public/index.php, meaning you shouldn't have to put the whole path in.
I looks like there's an error in your setup which is why the ErrorController is being called rather than IndexController.
What error do you get?

Comment: Yes (PHP+Apache) are working. The request cyrcle for running a zend application is completed... but all i know until now is that instead of getting to the IndexController, the ErrorController gets called and its view script error.phtml gets rendered.

Comment: I would guess you have a problem with your view then. I'm not going to be much more help though sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Your error.phtml doesn't show any stack trace.
You got 2 simple ways to show it :
- edit your .htaccess, and change the Application_env value :

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

If you application_env is set to "production", all the exception's stack trace is masked.

The other way is to edit the error.phtml file, and remove the condition around the environment to always disply the stack trace. (not the best option though)

This is not the answer (yet) but you'll have much more input for your problems, most notably the request parameters.

*edit : rewrote answer based on tries :)*

Comment: Yea sorry, i had that but my diagram wasn't really correct. Still the problem exists